# What is the correct way to setup readonly access to a MSSQLServer Analysis Cube

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap

People don't seem to be able to get the data from the cube unless unless I set the database permission to "full control" on the server. What is the right way to give read access (only) to a cube in Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum you need to do in order to give someone access to a cube is to set up a role, add the relevant accounts and groups to the role and then go into the cubes tab and change the permissions from "none" to "read" for the cubes you wish them to see.